# Sqlite update operations can I add value existing value?

Tags: java, android, database, algorithm, sqlite

```
"UPDATE " + DatabaseFıelds.TABLE_NAME + 
" SET " + DatabaseFıelds.SUBJECT_PROGRESS + " = " + 
point + " WHERE " + DatabaseFıelds.SUBJECT_ID + " = " + id;
```

this query updates my value, but I want it to add to existing value. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add the value of `point` to the existing value of `DatabaseFıelds.SUBJECT_PROGRESS`, right? You can do it like this:

```
"UPDATE " + DatabaseFıelds.TABLE_NAME + 
" SET " + DatabaseFıelds.SUBJECT_PROGRESS + " = "  + 
DatabaseFıelds.SUBJECT_PROGRESS + " + " + point + 
" WHERE " + DatabaseFıelds.SUBJECT_ID + " = " + id;
```

Comment: yes for example I'm student its my point when I know question my point will grow

Comment: The sql statement is correct. I don't know how you use it.

Comment: I tried but firstly my point is one times changing and when I continue value its same